# How to specify readonly=false when opening a lucene directory?

Tags: java, lucene

I'm using `FSDirectory.open(Paths.get("/path/to/index))` to obtain a reference to the directory that contains my lucene index data.

I'd like to obtain an IndexReader which passes `readOnly` as true as it gives better performance according to docs.

None of the methods on `DirectoryReader` provide this option. Any ideas what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that only applies to very old versions of Lucene.

For example, looking at the `IndexReader` javadoc for [version 3.5.0](https://lucene.apache.org/core/3_5_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexReader.html) (way back in 2011), it states:

> *it's possible to open a read-only IndexReader using the static open methods that accept the boolean readOnly parameter. Such a reader has better concurrency as it's not necessary to synchronize on the isDeleted method.*

And you will see `open()` methods such as [this one](https://lucene.apache.org/core/3_5_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexReader.html#open(org.apache.lucene.store.Directory,%20boolean)) which take a "readonly" boolean.

However, from (at least) version 5.5.0 onwards, that no longer applies. Looking at the `IndexReader` javadoc for for that version, it states:

> *IndexReader instances are completely thread safe, meaning multiple threads can call any of its methods, concurrently.*

That remains the case in the latest version (currently 8.5.2).

So, unless you are using a very old version of Lucene, there is nothing you need to do for this. The [demo code samples](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_5_2/demo/overview-summary.html#overview.description) reflect this, also.

Comment: muchas gracias. i wonder why most of the google results for lucene still link to docs for way old versions